# Microservice Architecture dependency

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, message-queue, microservices

I have read a lot about microservice architecture but there is one thing that I dont understand how to achieve and hope you can help me with this...

Lets say I have a web-api-endpoint that recieves orders that an OrderMicroservice is responsible to handle. When order is put Inventory must be updated so OrderMS publish an event to subscribers (pub/sub using for example Nats) and InventoryMS will update the inventory due to it is subscribing to current event/message....I want to have a loose coupled architecture and use asynch calls to modules/MSs thats are interested in given info.

Given scenario will work perfectly fine if you have 1 instance of InventoryMS but what happens if you have scaled the InventoryMS horizontally i.e there are 5 instances of InventoryMS and all of them subscribes to inventory.change.event and will try to update the inventory?

What kind of architecture or message pattern should I use for a scenario like this with horizonatally scalled MS's so I can have a loose coupled architecture when MSs are dependent of each other? 
One way is that communication internally is made by REST-calls using circuit breaker pattern but then I feel that I build a monolite of MSs with some smartness (the circuit breaker)...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Point to Point messaging model and only one consumer will receive a mesage. In pub/sub model all subscribers will be notified.
 Example with [ActiveMQ](https://dzone.com/articles/jms-activemq).

Comment: Ok I'll have to investigate point to point messaging using Nats :), thanks!

Comment: If you use Java, check AvtiveMQ for example

Answer (score 4):

You can still use pub/sub models but you need to set the multiple instances so that only one would get a message. the specific depends on the pub/sub mechanism

for instance in AMQP systems (like RabbitMQ) you'd publish the events on an exchange. the consumer service would bing a queue to that exchange and all the instances of the same service would read from the same queue (so only one would handle any given message)

Another example is Kafka - in Kafka all the instances of the same service would use the same [consumer group](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) - so, again, only one instance of each subscribing service would get the message

Other pub/sub systems would have similar solutions.

Point to point to specific instances is not a great solution as it would couple the instances of the different services

Comment: Point to Point in ActiveMQ(destination:queue) is using round robin distribution on consumer side, so if you have more consumers they will not be coupled to specific instances. But you are right same thing you can achieve with pub/sub model as well.